# pendrive in Ubuntu 14.04LTS giving Error message

Tags: usb-drive

When I mount a pendrive on Ubuntu 14.04LTS I get following error message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb1 at /media/ubuntu/HP v240b:
Command-line `mount -t "vfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush" "/dev/sdb1" "/media/ubuntu/HP v240b"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: 
mount: /dev/sdb1: can't read superblock
```

Answer (score 0):

USB Flash Memory drives do fail, so I would make a complete backup of all your locally created content, then reformat it without the QuickFormat option, and then restore its apps and data. If the flash drive survives that, it's OK for now; if not, you have a copy of your data to save elsewhere.